# Chef list node as not heathy during knife status

Tags: chef-infra, knife

During running the following command:

```
knife status --hide-healthy

167 hours ago, XXXX...... centos 6.5.
0 minutes ago, XXXX...... centos 6.5.
```

I have got some nodes which just run chef-client **successfully** (0 minutes ago).

The node[chef-client][interval] is default 1800. However for some nodes it works and for other no. The run-list the same and client.rb too.

> `chef-client --version Chef: 12.0.3`

I am asking because on the Chef Server I see many nodes which not run chef client periodically and I cant understand why

Comment: Did you configure chef-client it to run on the nodes via crontab or as a service ? The interval on itself is just an indication, it is not telling it to register a service if it's not started as daemon, the chef_client cookbook can be of some help to configure this.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I have figured out that chef-client running as a service. The nodes which were listed as not healthy don't update periodically the restart of `/etc/init.d/chef-client restart` fix the issue